# What transportation is available from Costa Rica to Nicaragua?

Tags: budget, public-transport, transportation, costa-rica, nicaragua

We will be flying in to San Jose Costa Rica in January for 3 weeks, and would like to spend part of that time in Nicaragua. What is the easiest, least expensive way to get to Lake Nicaragua area?

Comment: Easiest and least expensive are rarely the same.

Answer (score 4):

### Bus it, Man

[Rome2rio says there are three bus services from San Jose, Costa Rica to somewhere near Lake Nicaragua](https://www.rome2rio.com/s/Costa-Rica/Lake-Nicaragua) ([Peñas Blancas, Costa Rica](https://www.google.fr/maps/place/Pe%C3%B1as+Blancas,+Costa+Rica/@11.1562172,-85.591569,12z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x8f75a9f789e05e67:0x8cacfe7ba2cd7a1d) or [Rivas, Nicaragua](https://www.google.fr/maps/place/Rivas,+Nicaragua/@11.346715,-85.7192373,11z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x8f744ec14f202653:0x9b7a8aa527fa8791)). Indeed following up on the bus company websites one finds the information below. Note that ticket costs often don't include immigration taxes to enter/exit Costa Rica and Nicaragua. At the time of writing these are as follows ([according to the Trans Nica FAQ page](http://transnica.com/new/preguntas-frecuentes/)):

> - Costa Rica: Salida $7USD y entrada $2USD.
> - Nicaragua: Salida $2 y entrada si es extranjero $14USD, si es nicaragüense $1.

#### 1. Trans Nica

[Trans Nica buses depart from San Jose and stop in Rivas.](http://transnica.com/new/horarios-para-su-conveniencia/) At the time of writing there are three economy and one executive departures per day. The economy fare is 54`USD` return, and the executive fare is 76`USD` return.

For more information [here is the FAQ page of Trans Nica (in Spanish)](http://transnica.com/new/preguntas-frecuentes/). Below is a screenshot taken from the linked page, showing detailed information on the bus service:

[image: Trans Nica fare comparison]

#### 2. Marvelus Travels

[Marvelus Travels operates a bus from San Jose to Rivas.](http://marvelustravel.com/transportation-shuttle-bus-taxi-minivans/costa-rica-bus-trip-taxi-transport-ground-ride-transfers-vans-international-routes-roads-service.html) At the time of writing there are two departures per day. The fare is 37`USD` one-way. The journey duration is advertised as 7 hours. Below is a screenshot of the Marvelus Travels website:

[image]

#### 3. Bus 505

[According to this unofficial website, there seems to be a mysterious bus n. 505 which serves the route from San Jose to Peñas Blancas.](http://www.monteverdeinfo.com/costa-rica/bus-schedule.htm) There are six departures per day, of which two are express buses. In this case you are looking at 6 hours to cover 293km (not sure if this is the express service or not). Quoting from the linked website:

> #### 505 SANTA ROSA AND PEÑAS BLANCAS (from San José)
>
> - DEP. ev. day from 100 mts north of Terminal Coca Cola at 4:30, 5:00, 7:00, 7:45, 13:20, 16:10; RET. 5:00, 7:15, 10:30, 10:40, 13:30, 14:45, 15:30.
> - Only DEP. 4:30 , 7:00 and RET: 10:30, 13:30 are express buses.
> - 293 km, 6:00 hrs.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a bus from San Jose or any major city (Transnica, Nicabus and other big companies have good deals with comfortable buses).

You can fly from any airport for around $100, give or take.

Or you can boat it.

Source: a Costa Rican

Answer (score 1):

Take a national bus to Penas blancas, walk over the border and the take a national bus to your final destination, on the way back you can take a boat and cross over to Los Chiles (Costa Rica). I did it when I was visiting Nicaragua after arriving by plane to Costa Rica